# R - How to assign years to Integers

Tags: r

I am new to R still and I have issue. I have DataSet which stores data for multiple countries for multiple years. However, years are indicated as Sessions from 1 to X where one is 1946.

Is there a way how to sort Session column in my dataset and change Integers to corresponding years. Where 1 = 1946, 2 = 1947, 3 = 1948? I would do it manually but as there are almost 9K rows with multiple 1, and 2 etc. I need some R workaround that does this fast. And count find anything online.

Comment: Are your years all coded so that 1 = the same reference year (1946) and 2 is always 1947 and so on? If so, then `dataset$year <- dataset$year + 1945`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a column named `Session` in dataframe `df`, the solution with `dplyr` would be as easy as:

```
df <- mutate(df, Session = Session + 1945) %>%
    arrange(Session)
```